# Creating a method/function with dynamic argument arrangement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, arguments

This is seen in jQuery all the time and am wondering how they do it. I'll give you an example off the bat:

in jQuery's `fadeIn()` animation you can put in a combination of three different types arguments:

```
.fadeIn([duration ] [, complete ] );
.fadeIn( options );
.fadeIn( [duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] );
```

As shown, you can put in different arguments and the order is not important. What would be the appropriate, or most practical, way of accepting these arguments and handling them accordingly like the `fadeIn()` method does? I'm building a plugin that would pretty much handle the arguments the same way:

```
.flipAnimation([newvalue]);
.flipAnimation([newvalue] [, duration]);
.flipAnimation([newvalue][, duration][, complete()]);
.flipAnimation(options);
```

Thank you.

Comment: you will be looking at [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use `arguments`.  Every function has an `arguments` variable in scope that contains all arguments passed to the function, regardless of its signature.  For instance:

```
a = function() { console.log(arguments); };
a(); // []
a(1,2,3,4);  // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, you can use this combined with `typeof` to check how the user invoked your function.  e.g.

```
foo = function() {
    if(typeof(arguments[0]) == 'function') {
        // do something
    } else if(typeof(arguments[0]) == 'object') {
        // do something else
    }
};

foo( function() { return 'hi'; } );
foo( {foo: 'bar'} );
// both will do something
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it pass all the parameter in a javascript object.

When you need it, just access to that object attribute, something like

```
function foo(params) {
    if(params['attr1'] != null) {
         // use it
    }

    if(params['attr2'] != null) {
         // use it
    }

    ...
    // so on
}
```

**Update** more details how you can use it. Something make you misunderstand me was removed

```
params = {callback: callbackFunctionName OR functionCode, attr1: someValue ... }

// now just call it
foo(params);
// and you have your callback in params['callback'] 
// ofcouse you should review its type
// you have params['attr1'] = someValue
// inside your foo.
```